# rails 5 has_many through order on through table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to order a `has_many through` relationship on a column in the through table

```
class DoctorProfile
  has_many :doctor_specialties
  has_many :specialties, through: :doctor_specialties

class Specialty
  has_many :doctor_specialties
  has_many :doctor_profiles, through: :doctor_specialties

class DoctorSpecialty
  belongs_to :doctor_profile
  belongs_to :specialty
```

I'd like the doctor specialties to be ordered by the column `ordinal` on `DoctorSpecialty`. Specifically this error happens when using `includes`

`DoctorProfile.includes(:specialties).all`

I've tried

`has_many :specialties, -> { order 'doctor_specialties.ordinal' }, through: :doctor_specialties`

```
DoctorProfile Load (0.6ms)  SELECT  "doctor_profiles".* FROM "doctor_profiles" ORDER BY "doctor_profiles"."id" ASC LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 1]]
  DoctorSpecialty Load (0.8ms)  SELECT "doctor_specialties".* FROM "doctor_specialties" WHERE "doctor_specialties"."doctor_profile_id" = 1
  Specialty Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "specialties".* FROM "specialties" WHERE "specialties"."id" = 69 ORDER BY doctor_specialties.ordinal
```

and receieve a missing FROM -clause error `PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "doctor_specialties"`

How can I define the order on the through table so specialties are returning in ascending order?

**Note:**

I was able to get this working by adding a `default_scope` to `DoctorSpecialty`

`default_scope { order('ordinal ASC') }`

However, I'm still wondering if there is a way to do it on the `has_many through`

Comment: What's the SQL that is generated?

Comment: @DavidAldridge added the SQL

Comment: @user2954587 Did you figure out if there's a way to do this with has_many? I have a very similar problem now and defining a default_scope on the through table doesn't work for me.

Comment: @AdColvin `:specialties, -> { order 'doctor_specialties.ordinal' }, through: :doctor_specialties`

Comment: @AdColvin actually, looking back i just did a default scope on the joining table. answer below

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to get it working using

```
class DoctorProfile
    has_many :specialties, -> { order 'doctor_specialties.ordinal' }, through: :doctor_specialties

end

class DoctorSpecialty < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :doctor_profile
  belongs_to :specialty

  default_scope { order('ordinal ASC') }

end
```

Comment: Thank you for the order ('table.column') hint!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what's causing your error but you haven't completed the has many through relationship on the Specialty side. Should be `has_many :doctor_profiles, through: :doctor_specialties`

Also for this line in DoctorProfiles `has_many :specialties, through: doctor_specialties`, `doctor_specialties` needs to be a symbol

As for the ordering I think you need to do a `joins` instead of an `includes`

like `DoctorProfile.joins(:doctor_specialties).order("doctor_specialties.ordinal ASC")`

Comment: that was not the issue but I updated the post, thanks

Comment: I do want to use an includes but the `joins` comment is helpful. thanks for pointing that out. the solution above I think is the right one I am looking for with a `default_scope` on `DoctorSpecialty` because I need to serialize the specialties later